# How do I avoid access violation exception calling a CUDA Dll?

Tags: c#, dll, cuda, unmanaged, access-violation

I'm new with CUDA and not really familiar with C either. I wrote a Dll to implement CUDA methods (FFT) into my C# programm. I debugged first the dll as a console application to make sure it works properly, and just then built it as a dll. So my problem is that at the first call (cufftPlan1d()) of my dll causes an AccessViolationException. I've already looked up this blog and other google results so far, but nothing. I use unsafe code to handle pointers and allocate memory with Marshal.AllocHGlobal() method, so I don't really see where the problem is. Here is my code of my dll and the calling C# class:

Dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
unsigned int fftPlan(unsigned int* plan, int signal_size, int batch)
{
    if(cufftPlan1d(plan, signal_size, CUFFT_D2Z, batch) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) return 0;
    return 1;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int allocateMemory(double** signalGPU, cufftDoubleComplex** signalFft, int size)
{
    if(cudaMalloc(signalGPU, size) != cudaSuccess) return 0;
    if(cudaMalloc(signalFft, size+16) != cudaSuccess) return 0;
    return 1;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int fftCaller(unsigned int* plan, const double* real, double* realGPU,             cufftDoubleComplex* signalFft, cufftDoubleComplex* signalFftGPU, int size)
{
    cufftDoubleReal *idata=(cufftDoubleReal*)realGPU;
    if(cudaMemcpy(idata, real, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess) return 0;
    if(cufftExecD2Z(*plan, idata, signalFftGPU) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) return 0;
    if(cudaMemcpy(signalFft, signalFftGPU, size+16, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) !=    cudaSuccess) return 0;
    return 1;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void cudaClean(void* GPUPtr)
{
    cudaFree(GPUPtr);
}
```

and the wrapper class:

```
unsafe public class CudaFft
    public struct cufftDoubleComplex
    {
            public double x;
            public double y;
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe public delegate int fftPlan(int* plan, int signal_size, int batch);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe public delegate int allocateMemory(double** signalGPU, cufftDoubleComplex** signalFftGPU, int size);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe public delegate int fftcaller(int* plan, double* signal, double* signalGPU, cufftDoubleComplex* signalFft, cufftDoubleComplex* signalFftGPU, int size);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe public delegate int cudaclean(void* GPUPtr);

    public static int pDll, a;
    //static IntPtr signal, signalFft;
    unsafe static int* plan;
    unsafe static double* signal;
    unsafe static double** signalGPU;
    unsafe static int signal_size;
    unsafe static cufftDoubleComplex* signalFft;
    unsafe static cufftDoubleComplex** signalFftGPU;

    unsafe public static int Plan(int* plan, int signal_size, int batch)
    {
        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = DllImport.GetProcAddress(pDll, "fftPlan");


        fftPlan fftplan = (fftPlan)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(fftPlan));
        return fftplan(plan, signal_size, batch); //THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION 
    }  
    (...) //some irrelevant code here
    unsafe public CudaFft(int signal_length) //constructor
    {
        pDll = DllImport.LoadLibrary("d:\\CudaFft.dll");
        a = DllImport.GetLastError();
        signal_size = signal_length;
        signal = (double*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(signal_size * 8).ToPointer();
        signalFft = (cufftDoubleComplex*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal((signal_size / 2 + 1) * 16).ToPointer();
        CudaFft.Plan(plan, signal_length, 1);
        CudaFft.allocMemory(signalGPU, signalFftGPU, signal_size);
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Szabolcs

Comment: 'extern "C"' and 'CallingConvention.StdCall'? Did you try 'CallingConvention.Cdecl'?

Comment: I've just tried it, but the problem still occurs. Thanks, Szabolcs

Comment: I solved it, I just forget to allocate mamory for plan, so adding "plan = (int*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));" solves my issue.

Comment: Update your code, please. This will help people, who want to copy your code.

Comment: Please post an answer for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 1):

`plan` appears to never be allocated.